# Update or create row based on ID - Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

It's been several days since I'm stuck on this problem. I've tried everything I saw but I think I miss some logic of the Google Script.

I have a php form which send data on post to a Google Spreadsheet. It uses a Google Script to handle the request and update a Google Spreasheet. The problem is that I added one ID per row (generated on my web app and sent through my php form) but I can't find the way to compare the ID received on my Google Script in order to compare it to the ID of the last row of my spreadsheet. The goal is to replace the row if the ID already exists or add the new row at the end of my spreadsheet.

Here is the Google script I've found on the internet which works but does not handle row updates based on the ID
(The commented lines are the code I've tried to add but because of the fact that I cannot manage to log data when I'm sending my php form, I cannot visualize what I'm missing.)

````
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    // var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
    // var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    // var lastRowId = values[lastRow - 1][0];
    // var test = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    // Logger.log(test);
    // if (test.id == lastRowId) {
    //   return;  
    // }

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow}))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}```
````

Comment: I thought that in order to correctly understand your question, when you provide the sample input value of `e` from your PHP form and your sample input Spreadsheet, it will help to think of the solution. So, can you provide them?

Comment: Also  note `sheetName` is not defined.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for the answer. To be honnest, that's the problem I do not understand what exactly is e and I've tried to log it but it's empty when I use the debugger tool (because there is no form sent) and I do not know how to log the data when the form is sent

Comment: @TheWizEd Thanks for the answer. I added it on my post but this was not the problem since it was already on my Google Script

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that you cannot provide the sample input value of `e` from your PHP form. In that case, can you put a script `DriveApp.createFile("log.txt", JSON.stringify(e))` after the line of `function doPost (e) {`? By this, the value of `e` is created as a text file and the value can be seen. By the way, you cannot provide your sample input Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct? Because I thought that in your situation, it is required to know the value of `e` and Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

#### Maybe something like this

```
function lfunko(obj) {
  const [hA, ...arr] = "obj.2d";
  const idx = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => { idx[h] = i; });
  let idA = arr.map(r => r[idx["ID"]]);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const [h, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let idx1 = {};
  h.forEach((h, i) => { idx1[h] = 1; })
  vo = []
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let n = idA.indexOf(idx1["ID"])
    if (!~n) {
      vo.push(r)
    } else {
      vo.push(arr[n])
    }
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vo));
  sh.getRange(1,1,vo.length,vo[0].length).setValues(vo);
}
```